# Go to home in a WP8 application

Tags: vb.net, xaml, windows-phone-8, back-button, homescreen

I would like to know if it was possible in VB.NET for WP8, when the user clicks on the back key of the phone, to go to the main menu (home with the tiles) without really quiting the app (because it has to stay in the multitask "as is")
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you want to do that? The user expect that he closed the app permanently.

There is no way to do this behavior.

You also need to understand these points:

- When you press the start key or launch another app:

  > If your app is in the foreground and the user launches another app or presses the Start button to return to the home screen your app is
  >   suspended in memory. When the user returns to your app by pressing
  >   the back button or by selecting it from the task switcher, your app
  >   is resumed.If the device needs to free up memory to make sure that
  >   the foreground app is responsive, suspended apps are terminated and
  >   info about the state of the terminated apps are saved
- If you need to do multitasking then choose the appropriate Background
  agent for you scenario.

  > Only one app runs at a time on Windows Phone, but background agents provide a way for your app to perform tasks, even while it’s not
  >   running in the foreground. There are several different types of
  >   agents that are provided to enable specific phone features, but the
  >   two general purpose agents are the periodic agent and the
  >   resource-intensive agent.

  For more info, see Background agents [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202942%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)
- Background transfers

  > If you would like your app to be able to download files in the background but the app doesn’t need to execute any code as you would
  >   with a background agent, consider using the background transfer
  >   feature.

  For more info, see background transfers, [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202955%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: OK so if I just want the app to quit to the homescreen when the user press the back key on the main page, I have to use `Application.Terminate`, isn't it ?

Comment: No, It's implemented by default. And if you want you can override to ask User if he want to leave or not (In case he misscicked it ). But normally this will be in games and you won't need it.

check this snippet


  protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnBackKeyPress(e);
            MessageBoxResult mb = MessageBox.Show("You want exit the page", "Alert", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);

            if (mb != MessageBoxResult.OK)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
        }

Comment: The strange thing is (my app is not a game) when I press Back on the main page, it goes to the page I was just before, not to the home or to the last app I used.